# invalid syntax dictionary ...512: ("Butter", 4.50), }

Tags: syntax-error

there is an **invalid syntax** at **line 5** (512: ("Beurre", 4.50),
Could you please help me get it right ?
I thought it was the coma at the first sight, but it doesn't change anything
I am lost thank you

```
produits = {
  452: ("Lait", 2.50),
  378: ("Chocolat", 3.50),
  908: ("Eau", 2.00)
  512: ("Beurre", 4.50),
  }
```

Comment: a comma is missing after " 908: ("Eau", 2.00)", just add it and it works.

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify which language this is written in.